# Retrofit2 duplicates query parameter

Tags: parameters, duplicates, retrofit2

Retrofit2 duplicates my query parameter. I think it's a bug, but I did not find anything about it.

```
@GET("mock/netverificationProces")
Call<NetverificationProcessAuthorizationResponse> netverificationProcessAuthorization(@Query("authorizationToken") String token);
```

In my API class I normally use:

```
response = api.netverificationProcessAuthorization("XYZ").execute();
```

but this calls:

```
https://IP_ADDRESS/mock/netverificationProces?authorizationToken=XYZ?authorizationToken=XYZ
```

Do I something wrong?

EDIT:
OkHttpClient header interceptor:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
Interceptor headerInterceptor = chain -> {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder();
    if (jwt != null) {
      requestBuilder.header("Authorization", token);
    }
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  };
builder.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor);
return builder
      .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .readTimeout(apiTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .build();
```

Maybe Authorization header?

Comment: probably you have an interceptor that's adding the auth token again? Cause retrofit never does so.

Comment: I've got only header interceptor, no authorization interceptors at all.

Comment: The authorisation is added in header. Check your header interceptor. Did you write it?